Create a multivalued Bar Chart in Grafana with Prometheus as data source
I have data stored in Prometheus and I am trying to create a multivalued bar chart from it as following:

However, I want to group bars not by time but by a custom label.
Here is the Prometheus query I use in Grafana:
sum by (field_1, field_2) (metric_name{field_1="ABC", field_2="multiple"})

I want X-Axis to be field_1, Y-Axis to be the metric value, and I want all "field_2" values to be grouped in 1 bar chart. Currently, the query places multiple "field_2" values in separate bars right next to each other as following:

My Grafana version is v8.4.5
How can I display the data as in the first picture?
